# How to get input in a string in c++?

Tags: c++

I wrote following function

```
 void validateUser(void)
 {
         string uName;
         string uPassword;
         char c;

         map <char*, char*> authMap;
         authMap["balaji"] = "balaji";
         authMap["rohan"] = "rohan";

         cout << "Please Enter your user name :";
         cin >> uName;
         cout << "Please Enter your password :";
        // initTermios(0);
         while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
         {
           uPassword.push_back(c);
         }
         cout << "YOU Entered :: "<<  uPassword <<std::endl;
}
```

When i executed the above function, i found that after entering user name i press enter key then control does not enter into while loop even if i did not entered any password string.
Ant solution to above ? Thanks in advace.

Comment: Note that the `map` will be keyed by the address of the string literal, not the string content. Suggest using `map<std::string, std::string>` instead.

Comment: Why `map <char*, char*>` and not `map <string, string>`?

Comment: @hmjt and m0skit0 ..thanks for suggestion , i will use map<string, string>, what about issue i mentioned above?

Comment: Your while loop is a duplication of the [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function.

Comment: @hmjt and m0skit0 sory guys, problem  while using map<string, string> is that when i will try to pass the map value to "strcmp()" function, it gives following error: error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'

Comment: Don't use `strcmp()`, it is possible to just use `==` to compare two `std::string` or to compare a `std::string` to a `char*`. Note you can access the C style represent via `std::string::c_str())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newline character entered as a result of entering the username is still in standard input, and it is this that is read next thus the loop terminating condition is immeditately false. You need to skip past the newline character, which can be achieved using [`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
cin.ignore();
```

Suggest not mixing use of C and C++ IO functions (I am unsure of the exact rules how this interact but I prefer to avoid it):

```
while (cin.get(c) && '\n' != c)
{
    uPassword.push_back(c);
}
```

or just use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
getline(cin, uPassword);
```

As mentioned in my comment, the map will be keyed by the address of the string literal, not the string content. Suggest using `map<std::string, std::string>` instead.